# How do i implement an Android native library into my android project? Specifically the biemmeIOdemo Library

Tags: android, modbus, rs485

I am developing an app that needs to read data from a modbus RTU slave device connected through RS485.  The only place online that i could find a solution to this problem is here.  http://www.biemmeitalia.net/libraries/install.html

The link to the source code on github is here:  https://github.com/biemme/biemmeIOdemo

The question i have is how do i use this library in my android app.  I am developing in Android Studio.

Comment: Follow the directions at your link?  But be aware it is only likely to work on their hardware!  What sort of Android device are you targeting?

Comment: The problem is that their link says to download the BiemmeModbus.jar wrapper and the only code i could find available was on github and it is not packaged as a .jar.  I am using a tablet that has an RS485 connector built into it.  It is an off brand tablet from china.  It is running Android 4.1.  I do know that the serial port for that connection is /dev/ttyS1/.

Comment: im hoping that i can use their library and adjust parameters such as the serialport location to work with my setup. The directions in the link say, "By default, the port that will be opened in the Ltouch development board for rs485 communication is /dev/s3c2410_serial1"  so i am assuming the part of the library that connects to the serialport is the correct code that i need as well. I just need to be able to change /dev/s3c2410_serial1 to /dev/ttyS1/.  This library already has the modbus layer build on top of the serialport code.  Mainly this is the part i am interested in.